# What do I have to add to my JS driven game to interact With an external game joystick/controller?

Tags: javascript, game-development

What do I have to add to my JS driven game to interact  With an external game joystick/controller?

What I have is a JS-driven game with buttons to control movement of a Paddle so it can “hit” a game piece.

I only have `<button>`s to click. What do I have to add to my JS driven game to interact with an external game joystick/controller to click on.

I do nothing with `mouseX` or `mouseY`, just these clickable buttons.

The game piece bounces off 4 walls. It is the job of the user to steer the Paddle so it “hits” the game piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use the [html5 gamepad API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Gamepad_API) if you're doing this in the browser. Just make sure to check out the browser compatibility section.

[This blog post](https://beej.us/blog/data/javascript-gamepad/) looks pretty good but here's a snippet from there.

```
// https://beej.us/blog/data/javascript-gamepad/
// Show button state

let gamepads = navigator.getGamepads();

// Blindly assuming this is connected
let gp = gamepads[0];

// Blindly assuming there's a button
let button = gp.buttons[0];

if (button.pressed) {
    console.log("Button pressed!");
} else {
    console.log("Button not pressed");
}

console.log("Button value: " + button.value);
```

Comment: Oh my goodness. So it appears that I have to somehow <script> include this API **or** is it included in the API?? pre-loaded as part of the Browser code. For example, if I have a bunch of <button>’s in **my** code, will the built-in API automatically find them?

Comment: Sure would be nice if I didn't have to do anything, i.e., the Mac Browser did all the work with its on-board API. It should be obvious by now that I don't have a Game Controller for my iMac. Guess I'll squeeze out a recommendation from my son.

Comment: @John nope you don't have to include or do anything to get that API, it's a browser standard now (unless that compatibility chart says it's not for your browser). But if you have html buttons working currently, then you basically have to take your 'onClick' logic and change it to 'if button.pressed'. You might run into some different problems but should get you started, good luck!

Comment: Okay, I found a thorough description of this API   I SEE the if button.pressed call. So, this tells me I have to somehow delete my <button on click=“doThis()”> and substitute the API call. If I’m right, I can **not** have a JS game and a IOS button pusher. ???